# Are there any plans for okhttp to implement http2 using async sockets?

Tags: nio, okhttp, http2

OkHttp seems to use blocking I/O and one thread per stream in its http2 implementation.

Are there any plans for okhttp to implement http2 using async sockets?

Answer (score 6):

Yep. But we're trying to do it with Kotlin coroutines as the underlying abstraction, so there's a lot of work to do.

Note that NIO and async I/O is more scalable but not necessarily faster. That is, for a client making fewer than say, 8 concurrent calls there's actually a performance cost to async I/O.

What's your use case?

Comment: the use case is ~30 requests for json "index" files, followed by about 50 requests *per index file*, one for each asset listed in the index. The goal is essentially to maximize concurrency while minimizing # of threads.

Comment: Cool. Synchronous for this use case isn’t so bad, but async might save some memory.